# How do I allow X11 forwarding in root (or with sudo) when accessing Raspberry Pi via SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, xorg, sudo

I have been able to forward X11 through normal executions (e.g. `xeyes` as opposed to `sudo xeyes`), but with my purposes I need to access the same applications with root access. I have not been able to figure out how to execute these applications with root access, often giving an X11 error in PuTTY. Here's an example, from login to logoff, an attempt to forward an X11 application:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo qbittorrent
PuTTY X11 proxy: Authorisation not recognised
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display localhost:10.0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Aborted
```

It works without the usage of `sudo` so I am not sure what the issue is here. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: It's about `~/.Xauthority`. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118295/108618).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski this involves my `.Xauthority` file to have entries within it, which is not the case as it is empty. Is there a way I can make it generate a new entry?

Comment: Okay, so I figured out how to ad an entry, then did what was said in the guide, but still the exact same results occur, still exclusively in root! This really makes no sense to me...

Comment: A quick and dirty fix: `cp /home/$SUDO_USER/.Xauthority ~` (that is assuming your `sudo` preserves the environment, if it doesn't, need to preserve the `DISPLAY` value)